# Iterate over lists without two duplicates in a row

Tags: python

I would like to iterate over lists of integers in a similar way to:

```
itertools.product(range(n), repeat=5)
```

If n = 3 this gives:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 0, 0, 2, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 2, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 2, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
[...]
```

However I want only those tuples that don't have the same number twice in a row. So (0,0,1,0,0) would be excluded as would many others.

How can you do this?

Comment: What about (1, 2, 0, 1, 3)? Should this be excluded as well?

Comment: I think that would be included. It's not "twice in a row"

Comment: Yes it should be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably more efficient to generate the sequences without consecutive duplicates yourself, rather than generating all of the sequences with `itertools.product` and filtering them. I'd use a recursive generator like this:

```
def gen(seq, n, prefix=()):
    if n == 0:
        yield prefix
        return

    for x in seq:
        if not prefix or x != prefix[-1]:
             yield from gen(seq, n-1, prefix+(x,))
```

example output:

```
>>> list(gen(range(3), 5))
[(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 0, 2, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 2, 1),
 (0, 1, 2, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 2, 0, 2),
 (0, 1, 2, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 2, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 2, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 0, 2, 0),
 (0, 2, 0, 2, 1),
 (0, 2, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 2, 1, 0, 2),
 (0, 2, 1, 2, 0),
 (0, 2, 1, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 2),
 (1, 0, 1, 2, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 2, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 2, 0, 2),
 (1, 0, 2, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 2, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 2, 0, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0, 2, 0),
 (1, 2, 0, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 2, 1, 0, 2),
 (1, 2, 1, 2, 0),
 (1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
 (2, 0, 1, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 1, 0, 2),
 (2, 0, 1, 2, 0),
 (2, 0, 1, 2, 1),
 (2, 0, 2, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 2, 0, 2),
 (2, 0, 2, 1, 0),
 (2, 0, 2, 1, 2),
 (2, 1, 0, 1, 0),
 (2, 1, 0, 1, 2),
 (2, 1, 0, 2, 0),
 (2, 1, 0, 2, 1),
 (2, 1, 2, 0, 1),
 (2, 1, 2, 0, 2),
 (2, 1, 2, 1, 0),
 (2, 1, 2, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: Yes, probably the quickest route if the op has hand on the generator.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another take on the recursive generator approach that is based on excluding the value from the calling recursion rather than passing down the whole result:

```
def comb(A,n,x=None):
    return ([v]+r for v in A if v!=x for r in comb(A,n-1,v)) if n else [[]]
```

Output:

```
for p in comb(range(3),5):print(p)
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 2, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 0, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

[EDIT] alternative version that returns a list of lists

```
def comb(A,n,x=None):
    return [[v]+r for v in A if v!=x for r in comb(A,n-1,v)] if n else [[]]
```

Comment: That's an interesting alternative implementation. You could replace the `yield from` with `return` if you don't mind mixing up your return type a bit (sometimes a generator expression, sometimes a list of lists).

Comment: Easily, see my [EDIT]. But one function cannot be both a generator and alternatively return value.  Python makes it a generator as soon as there is at least one Yield in the function.  I would make two and name the generator `iComb` to distinguish it from regular `comb`

Comment: Right, but you can `return` a generator expression without being a generator function. You don't *need* to turn the genexp into a list comprehension if you don't want the eager evaluation.

Comment: I see, I didn't get what you meant initially.  "Return a generator or return a list of list" not make a function that is sometimes a generator and sometimes returns a value.  Got it now.  I like the idea (adjusted the answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
output = [
          lst for lst in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3) 
          if not any(i==j for i, j in zip(lst[:-1],lst[1:]))
         ]
```

Comment: You don’t need to wrap the generator in a comprehensive list for `any` as this can directly eat the generator. For op: thsi `zip` construction will yield all values of `lst` skipping the last one and then skipping the first one.

Comment: Indeed, edited!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprensive list with a guard:

```py
n = 3
repeat = 5
[l for l in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=repeat) if not any(l[n-1] == l[n] for n in range(1, repeat))]
```

This will filter out any line with at least one value identical to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use higher-level functions you can check that the number of groups in a groupby is that same as the repeat.

```
n = 3
r = 5
out_gen = filter(
    lambda x: len(tuple(itertools.groupby(x)))==r, 
    itertools.product(range(n), repeat=r)
)
```